# Laravel 5.3 api routes are redirecting even when all middleware is commented out

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5, redirect, postman

I am writing a RESTful API with a new Laravel 5.3 app.

I have a resource defined in `routes/api.php` like so:

```
Route::resource('/simple-path', 'Api\ControllerName');
```

There is no middleware added on the route itself, nor is there any added in the constructor of that controller, nor is there any middleware added in any parent controllers/classes.

However, Laravel(?) keeps 302 redirecting to `/` for any HTTP verb other than `GET`, and I am driving myself *crazy* trying to figure out why. Even if I comment out all the middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` it still redirects whenever I run a simple POST call to `/simple-path` in curl or PostMan.

Now, don't get me wrong, I *want* the `auth:api` middleware on my api, especially for POST or PUT requests, but I can't figure out what is causing it to redirect when there isn't any middleware running in the first place (so far as I can tell).

I've read all the docs on middleware that I can find. I am wondering if there is something other than middleware that could be causing this? This is a fairly fresh app, so I have not changed much from the basic install.

Comment: Are you extending a controller that does controller level middleware? https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware (so within a controller method)

Comment: if you put in your routes/api.php `Route::post('/test', function(){ return response(["message" =>"test"], 200); });` and try to post to `http://yourpath.com/api/test` do you get anything? because you should get the correct response back.

Comment: Its perfectly working without any errors if you have removed the middleware?

Comment: Just do "php artisan route:list" and check which controller does post and put method uses?

Comment: @AfikDeri your test worked, and led me to realize that my controller action was type-hinting a FormRequest subclass I had quickly set up earlier that seems to be triggering it. I had a 'required' validation rule on one of the params, and when I removed all 'required' validation rules, the request no longer redirects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question here. The redirection was not due to middleware but due to a `FormRequest`. I was type hinting a `FormRequest` subclass I had created in the `store()` function on my controller class, and this caused it to run `rules()` for validation first. When it saw that a required field was missing, the `FormRequest` class was redirecting via its own `response()` method. So I simply added this to my `FormRequest` subclass (for now):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

public function response(array $errors)
{
    return Response::json($errors, 400);
}
```

Comment: bro i have some doubts regarding the same redirection. can you pls join me on this chat room chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135960/laravel

Answer (score 9):

To fix this redirection, just set header parameter "Accept" to "application/json" while calling laravel api routes from rest clients, and it will work fine.

Comment: in 100 years i wouldn´t have thought about something like that, this saved my day ;-)